# Function for 2D Point Projection

Tags: matlab, projection, affinetransform

I have two sets of points stored in 2x9 matrices. One set is input points, and the other set is the desired output. How can I determine a transform between these two matrices, then generate an equation that could allow me to plug in any point and receive a corresponding output point relative to the other points? I'd prefer answers that are do-able in MatLab. Thanks!

Comment: IT would help if you could share your data (your set of points), so if someone wants to help you he has something to work on. By the way, did you try anything yourself ? Or do you have an idea on how to approach the problem ? (if yes share it too, it will show some effort on your part and motivate someone to help you).

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for interpolation. MATLAB has built in interpolation functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have

```
OUTPUT = INPUT * SOME_TRANSFORM
```

Assuming that it is linear.

Matlab has a matrix division operation : http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html

So for given input and output:

```
SOME_TRANSFORM = INPUT \ OUTPUT
```

Then you can calculate for new input:

```
NEW_OUTPUT = NEW_INPUT * SOME_TRANSFORM
```